# value is changing in page life cycle?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to make a simple website that will generate 2 numbers, and then the user will need to answer the correct result of addition of 2 of these numbers..

This is my ASPX:

```
<div id="questionContainer">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>  
        <div id="firstNumber">
            <%=firstNum %>
        </div>
        <div id="operator">
            <%=operatorString %>
        </div>
        <div id="secondNumber">
           <%=secondNum %>
        </div>
        <div id="answerWrapper">

                    <input type="text" id="answer" name="answer" placeholder="your answer" />

            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="submit" name="submit" OnClick="AnswerQuestion" Text="Answer" />
              <input type="hidden" name="op" id="op" value="1" />
            <div id="error">
                <%=textForUser %>
            </div>
            </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>
```

And this is the code-behind:

```
protected static int firstNum;
    protected  static int secondNum;
    protected bool operatorTrueOrFalse = true;
    protected string operatorString = "+";
    protected GameLogic gl;
    protected static int answer;
    protected bool isItTrue;
    protected int userAnswer;
    protected string textForUser ="hello";
    protected string op;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {



        if (Page.IsPostBack || op == "1") // if solved X or null.
        {
            gl = new GameLogic();
            firstNum = gl.GenerateNumber(4);

            secondNum = gl.GenerateNumber(4);

            answer = gl.SolveFor(firstNum, secondNum, operatorString);
        }


    }

    public void AnswerQuestion(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request["answer"] != null)
        {
            userAnswer = int.Parse(Request["answer"]);

        }
        else
        {
            textForUser = "You need to type something";
        }


        if (answer == userAnswer)
        { // user has answered correctly.
            isItTrue = true;
            textForUser = "very good";
            op = "1";
        }
        else
        {// user has answered in - correctly.
            isItTrue = false;
            textForUser = "you are wrong";
            op = "0";
        }
    }
```

The problem is that I notice that every time I try to answer the question in the textbox, the numbers changes.. It's like I'm not answering the correct question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're regenerating a new number pair on postback it seems. Basically, the logic should be something like so, if you plan on staying on the same page repeatedly and simply posting answers:

```
1) Is this a postback?
   -> No: Generate a new value and store it in ViewState. Hold onto this value.
   -> Yes: Do we have a stored answer value in ViewState?
         -> No: Error? Something has gone wrong.
         -> Yes: Fetch that Value and hold on to it
2) On Button Click, Is the answer you entered the same as the generated value?
   -> No: Show Error
   -> Yes: Show Success, Then generate a new value and store it in ViewState
```

Your algorithm seems to be generating a new answer pair only during a post back, and on every postback.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're using **static variables**. These are **shared across all requests**. Don't use static variables for this purpose but store them elsewhere (f.e. Session,ViewState,Hiddenfield,...).

[Nine Options for Managing Persistent User State in Your ASP.NET Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300437.aspx)

- Application
- Cookies
- Form Post / Hidden Form Field
- QueryString
- Session
- New State Containers in ASP.NET
- Cache
- Context
- ViewState
- Web.config and Machine.config Files

... and of course database.